# Selecting records according to an item

Tags: ruby

I use Ruby 1.8.7.  I have a method which selects records according to the item that I pass to the method.

In my opinion, the code is not DRY.  Could somebody offer suggestions on refactoring it to make it shorter?

```
def get_record (id,item)
  case item
   when "category"
      @temp = Category.find(id)
   when "status"
      @temp = Status.find(id)
   when "industry"
     @temp = Industry.find(id)
   end
 return @temp.name if @temp
end
```

Comment: I'd say the code is a sample of bad programming, but I fail to see the relation with DRY principles.

Comment: What the method should return when @temp is nil?

Comment: before I pass Item i m checking it for nil? and empty string.

Comment: I aagree with you  Ingenu , but code leading to bugs and  anty dry principles :)

Answer (score 6):

You want to use `classify` and `constantize`:

```
require 'set'
AUTHORIZED = Set[Product, Status, Industry]
def get_record(id, item)
  model = item.classify.constantize
  raise "Go away, hacker" unless AUTHORIZED.include? model
  model.find(id).name
end
```

Be careful about security, as without the unless this will access any class in your system. This is just an example.

Comment: Marc-André Lafortune, incase this => CLASSES.fetch(item.to_sym).find(id) will be nil ? maybe is better to use CLASSES.fetch(item.to_sym).find(id).name rescue "" ?

Comment: `find(id)` will raise an exception if the record can not be found. Use `find_by_id` if you want `nil` in those cases.